# How to check if a URL is valid

Tags: ruby

How can I check if a string is a valid URL?

For example:

```
http://hello.it => yes
http:||bra.ziz, => no
```

If this is a valid URL how can I check if this is relative to a image file?

Comment: the url you provided seems to be an absolute url, what do you mean with relative to an image file

Comment: I posted an [UriValidator with specs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19423623/356895).

Answer (score 195, accepted):

### Notice:

As pointed by @CGuess, there's a bug with this issue and it's been documented for over 9 years now that validation is not the purpose of this regular expression (see https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6520).

---

Use the `URI` module distributed with Ruby:

```
require 'uri'

if url =~ URI::regexp
    # Correct URL
end
```

Like *Alexander Günther* said in the comments, it checks if a string *contains* a URL.

To check if the string *is* a URL, use:

```
url =~ /\A#{URI::regexp}\z/
```

If you only want to check for web URLs (`http` or `https`), use this:

```
url =~ /\A#{URI::regexp(['http', 'https'])}\z/
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work: `'http://:5984/asdf' =~ URI::regexp` and `'http::5984/asdf' =~ URI::regexp` both return 0. I expected them to return nil because none of them are valid URIs.

Comment: Isn’t :5984 port 5984 on localhost?

Comment: It actually checks if a variable contains a valid url. It will accept "http://example com" as a valid URL. Because it contains one. But it is not helpful if you expect the whole thing to be the URL.

Comment: This doesn't work for this `/images/myimage01.png` but the last is valid value for ccs background url or image tag source url.

Comment: gotqn: That is not a valid URL according to RFC 1738 though.

Comment: With regards to Ruby's handling of `^` and `$` on multi-line strings, shouldn't this be `/\A#{URI::regexp}\z/` instead?

Comment: Do not use this, it's so bad that `"http:"` passes this regexp.

Comment: DO NOT USE: There's a bug with this issue and it's been documented for over 9 years now that validation is not the purpose of this regular expression: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6520

Answer (score 48):

Similar to the answers above, I find using this regex to be slightly more accurate:

```
URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:ABS_URI]
```

That will invalidate URLs with spaces, as opposed to `URI.regexp` which allows spaces for some reason.

I have recently found a shortcut that is provided for the different URI rgexps. You can access any of `URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp.keys` directly from `URI::#{key}`.

For example, the `:ABS_URI` regexp can be accessed from `URI::ABS_URI`.

Comment: If you plan on using URI.parse at any point, this is definitely the way to go. URI::regexp matches certain URLs that will fail when later using URI.parse. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Sadly, this is only available on Ruby 1.9, not 1.8.

Comment: But, this works: `/^#{URI.regexp}$/`. The trouble is that `URI.regexp` doesn't anchor. A string with a space isn't validating the space as part of the URI, but everything leading up to the space. If that fragment looks like a valid URI, the match succeeds.

Comment: Applying awendt's comment to your proposals: `'http://:5984/asdf' =~ URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:ABS_URI]` gives 0, not nil; `'http::5984/asdf'=~ URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:ABS_URI]` gives 0; `'http://:5984/asdf' =~ /^#{URI.regexp}$/` gives 0; `'http::5984/asdf' =~ /^#{URI.regexp}$/` gives 0 as well. None of above regexps is fully correct, however they fail in very very odd situations only and this is not a big deal in most cases.

Comment: FYI, `URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:ABS_URI]` is identical to `/\A\s*#{URI::regexp}\s*\z/`

Comment: If you're using `URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:ABS_URI]` to validate that a URI has a scheme, be aware that matching it to `test:80` returns a truthy value.

Answer (score 43):

The problem with the current answers is that [a URI is not an URL](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

> A URI can be further classified as a locator, a name, or both.  The
>      term "Uniform Resource Locator" (URL) refers to the subset of URIs
>      that, in addition to identifying a resource, provide a means of
>      locating the resource by describing its primary access mechanism
>      (e.g., its network "location").

Since URLs are a subset of URIs, it is clear that matching specifically for URIs will successfully match undesired values. For example, [URNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_name):

```
 "urn:isbn:0451450523" =~ URI::regexp
 => 0
```

That being said, as far as I know, Ruby doesn't have a default way to parse URLs , so you'll most likely need a gem to do so. If you need to match URLs specifically in HTTP or HTTPS format, you could do something like this:

```
uri = URI.parse(my_possible_url)
if uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP) or uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTPS)
  # do your stuff
end
```

Comment: `uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP)` seems to be sufficient for both cases (http and https), at least in ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: still suffers the issues described by @skalee under the jonuts's answer

Comment: Summary, `URI.parse(string_to_be_checked).kind_of?(URI::HTTP)` does the job well.

Comment: Additionally, a very common mistyping in our database shows people tend to put to many slashes: `http:///neopets.com`, which unfortunately is also valid. Checking for the presence of a hostname fixes this: `uri = URI(str) ; %w[http https].include?(uri.scheme) && !uri.host.nil?`

Answer (score 19):

I prefer the [Addressable gem](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/). I have found that it handles URLs more intelligently.

```
require 'addressable/uri'

SCHEMES = %w(http https)

def valid_url?(url)
  parsed = Addressable::URI.parse(url) or return false
  SCHEMES.include?(parsed.scheme)
rescue Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError
  false
end
```

Comment: I just fed Addressable::URI.parse() with the weirdest strings to see what it rejects. It accepted crazy stuff. However the first string it did not accept was ":-)". Hmm.

Comment: How does this get so many upvotes? `Addressable::URI.parse` does not return nil with invalid input.

Comment: @mvw you'll have to be more specific about what is so cray. [Another poster asked the owner of the repo about a number of 'strange' URLs](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/issues/145), and he explained each one in detail. He signed off, saying it's less of a cost to be too permissive than being too restrictive. (BTW: I claim no expert knowledge over valid URLs!)

Comment: irb(main):034:0> valid_url?('http://asd!$@.com')
=> true

Answer (score 14):

For me, I use this regular expression:

```
/\A(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?\z/ix
```

Option:

- `i` - case insensitive
- `x` - ignore whitespace in regex

You can set this method to check URL validation:

```
def valid_url?(url)
  return false if url.include?("<script")
  url_regexp = /\A(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?\z/ix
  url =~ url_regexp ? true : false
end
```

To use it:

```
valid_url?("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805761/check-if-url-is-valid-ruby")
```

Testing with wrong URLs:

- `http://ruby3arabi` - result is invalid
- `http://http://ruby3arabi.com` - result is invalid
- `http://` - result is invalid
- `http://test.com\n<script src=\"nasty.js\">` (Just simply check "<script")
- `127.0.0.1` - not support IP address

Test with correct URLs:

- `http://ruby3arabi.com` - result is valid
- `http://www.ruby3arabi.com` - result is valid
- `https://www.ruby3arabi.com` - result is valid
- `https://www.ruby3arabi.com/article/1` - result is valid
- `https://www.ruby3arabi.com/websites/58e212ff6d275e4bf9000000?locale=en` - result is valid

Comment: The following is marked as valid: `"http://test.com\n<script src=\"nasty.js\">"`, and any domain that uses one of the [683 TLDs](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/tlds-2012-02-25-en) that are longer than 5 characters, or has two or more consecutive hyphens, is marked as invalid. Port numbers outside the 0-65535 range are allowed. FTP and IP addresses are obviously disallowed, but worth noting.

Comment: easily the best most applicable solution here for quick url checking. thanks

Comment: irb(main):051:0> valid_url?('http://127.0.0.1')
=> false

Answer (score 12):

This is a fairly old entry, but I thought I'd go ahead and contribute:

```
String.class_eval do
    def is_valid_url?
        uri = URI.parse self
        uri.kind_of? URI::HTTP
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
        false
    end
end
```

Now you can do something like:

```
if "http://www.omg.wtf".is_valid_url?
    p "huzzah!"
end
```

Comment: This works *much* better than the above solutions.  It doesn't have the caveats listed above, and also doesn't accept uris like javascript:alert('spam').

Comment: but it also matches `http:/`, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little bit old but here is how I do it. Use Ruby's URI module to parse the URL. If it can be parsed then it's a valid URL. (But that doesn't mean accessible.)

URI supports many schemes, plus you can add custom schemes yourself:

```
irb> uri = URI.parse "http://hello.it" rescue nil
=> #<URI::HTTP:0x10755c50 URL:http://hello.it>

irb> uri.instance_values
=> {"fragment"=>nil,
 "registry"=>nil,
 "scheme"=>"http",
 "query"=>nil,
 "port"=>80,
 "path"=>"",
 "host"=>"hello.it",
 "password"=>nil,
 "user"=>nil,
 "opaque"=>nil}

irb> uri = URI.parse "http:||bra.ziz" rescue nil
=> nil


irb> uri = URI.parse "ssh://hello.it:5888" rescue nil
=> #<URI::Generic:0x105fe938 URL:ssh://hello.it:5888>
[26] pry(main)> uri.instance_values
=> {"fragment"=>nil,
 "registry"=>nil,
 "scheme"=>"ssh",
 "query"=>nil,
 "port"=>5888,
 "path"=>"",
 "host"=>"hello.it",
 "password"=>nil,
 "user"=>nil,
 "opaque"=>nil}
```

See [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) for more information about the URI module.

Comment: I ran across this trying to fix a segfault.  Using `URI.parse` was actually the cause of this in Ruby 2.5.5 - I switched to @jonuts answer below if you don't mind some odd cases falling through. For my purposes I didn't care so that was ideal.

Answer (score 4):

In general,

```rb
/^#{URI::regexp}$/
```

will work well, but if you only want to match `http` or `https`, you can pass those in as options to the method:

```rb
/^#{URI::regexp(%w(http https))}$/
```

That tends to work a little better, if you want to reject protocols like `ftp://`.

Answer (score -2):

You could also use a regex, maybe something like http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View2D3B0109-C1B2-4B4E-BFFD-E8088CBC85FD.htm assuming this regex is correct (I haven't fully checked it) the following will show the validity of the url.

```
url_regex = Regexp.new("((https?|ftp|file):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:\#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\\.&]*)")

urls = [
    "http://hello.it",
    "http:||bra.ziz"
]

urls.each { |url|
    if url =~ url_regex then
        puts "%s is valid" % url
    else
        puts "%s not valid" % url
    end
}
```

The above example outputs:

```
http://hello.it is valid
http:||bra.ziz not valid
```

Comment: What about the mailto scheme? Or telnet, gopher, nntp, rsync, ssh, or any of the other schemes? URLs are a little more complicated than just HTTP and FTP.

Comment: Writing regex to validate URLs is difficult. Why bother?

Comment: @Rimian, you have to bother because all `URI` can do is in fact broken. See comments under the so many upvoted answers above. Not sure if Janie's answer is right but upvoting so hopefully people consider it more seriously. TBH I end up doing `url.start_with?("http://") || url.start_with?("https://")` because I need only HTTP and users should be responsible to use proper URLs.