# Custom URL validation method in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, uri, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I get this to work? Use !!URI.parse(url) or self.url ?

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :url
  validates :body, presence: true, :length => { :in => 6..240 }
  validates :body, uniqueness: true
  validates :url, presence: true
  validate :good_url
  require 'uri'
  def good_url
    errors.add(:url, 'not valid') unless URI.parse(url)
  end
end
```

Comment: Here is a question addressing the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167895/whats-a-good-way-to-validate-links-urls-in-rails-3

Comment: [An updated UriValidator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19423623/356895)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get it working, then how about:

```
errors.add(:url, 'not valid') if (url =~ URI::regexp).nil?
```

But if parsing urls is important to you, you might want to consider an alternative to ruby's standard URI implementation such as [addressable](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/), which handles UTF-8 characters, normalization and other edge cases that might be important depending on the context.

See also this: [check if url is valid ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805761/check-if-url-is-valid-ruby)