# Is it better to treat the path after the base URL as an instance of URI or string?

Tags: ruby, http, rest, uri

I am implementing a REST client in Ruby and am treating base URLs as instances of URI. For the path after the base URL, I am unsure whether to treat it also as a URI instance or as a string.

**Approach A**

```
base_url = URI("http://www.foo.com")
path = URI("/someaction")
```

**Approach B**

```
base_url = URI("http://www.foo.com")
path = "/someaction"
```

With both of the above approaches, I plan to call URI.join(base_url, path) before making my request. Which of the approaches would be considered a better practice?

Comment: I wouldn't use URI for URLs only. try `URI("uri:wtf")` and look [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16359999/413494)

Comment: Good to know, @fotanus. I'm surprised Ruby doesn't provide better built-in support for URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're worrying about something not worth worrying about. Let URI do what it's good at and designed to do:

```
base_url = URI("http://www.foo.com")
base_url.path = "/someaction"

base_url
=> #<URI::HTTP:0x00000102079d58 URL:http://www.foo.com/someaction>
```

Move along to something else.

If you need to manipulate a path that has been extracted from a URL, look at `split`, `basename`, `extname` and `dirname` from the File class. They do it in a nice standardized manner.