# NoMethodError in from Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize, nomethoderror, mechanize-ruby

running this code with mecahnize 2.7.3 and ruby 2.3.0dev:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new

agent.keep_alive = false
agent.open_timeout = 2
agent.read_timeout = 2
agent.ignore_bad_chunking = true
agent.gzip_enabled = false

url = 'http:%5C%5Cwww.scouts.org.uk'

agent.head(url)
```

Gives me this NoMethodError:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:648:in resolve': undefined     
methodlength' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:223:in `fetch'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize.rb:459:in `head
```

Is this a bug in mechanize or am I doing something wrong? If so how can it be fixed?

EDIT: the url is obviously worng, but im reading a lot of urls from a file and some of them might be wrong.

EDIT2: lets say I have a file like this http://pastie.org/9934756
I need to get the head of all the urls that are correct and ignore the others

Comment: No change with timeout at 10 or 20

Answer (score 1):

You write a wrong url, try this: `url = 'http://scouts.org.uk'`

Comment: I know. But there are a lot of urls and some of them may be wrong. Shouldnt the error be somethong like 404 not found or so?

Comment: @user1759796 your mistake in the "%5C%5C" - it's wrong url, it's must seems like: "http:// google.com/", "http:// scouts.org.uk" etc (without space)

Comment: See my edit. I know that the url is wrong, I just need to deal with it correctly

Comment: @user1759796 they all seems like first?

Comment: The urls may be different, valid or invalid. e.g 'http://something.com', "http://som%5c.com", "htt: asldkj.com", "ittp://something.com/" or whatever. I need to find the "good" urls and then process them with mechanize. If the url returns 404 thats no problem, because I can rescue that. 

Sorry stackoverflow cuts off the "http://" part

Answer (score 0):

Your target site is doing a redirect and uses meta refresh.  Update your code to include those methods:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.keep_alive = false
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
agent.redirect_ok = true
agent.open_timeout = 10
agent.read_timeout = 10
agent.ignore_bad_chunking = true
agent.gzip_enabled = false

url = 'http:%5C%5Cwww.scouts.org.uk'

begin
  page_head = agent.head(url)
rescue Exception => exception
  puts "Caught exception: #{exception.message}"
end
```

Result:

```
=> #Caught exception: undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: That doesnt change anything. You used the correct url (without the %5c). I need to get some sort of error that I can catch if this occures, not a nomethoderror. The problem is I dont know if all urls will have the correct format

Comment: Updated the code to catch the exception.  How you actually handle it is up to you, I just put a basic example.  More about [Ruby Exceptions](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Exception.html) and [exception handling](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html).

Comment: You may also want to check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805761/check-if-url-is-valid-ruby).

Answer (score 0):

You can add this method to check valid url or not :

```
require 'uri'
def valid?(url) 
    uri = URI.parse(url) 
    if uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP) == true
        puts '+'
    else 
        puts '-'
    end
rescue URI::InvalidURIError 
    puts 'false '
end

['http://web.de',
'http://web.de/',
'http:%5c%5cweb.de',
'http:web.de',
'foo://web.de',
'http://we b.de',
'http://|web.de'].each { |i|
    valid?(i)
}
```

> +
>
> +
>
> +
>
> +
>
> false
>
> false

Comment: For the url the OP provided, this returns `true` but it's not.

Comment: Yes, they return true for some of them that will work in a browser but Mechanize will still not load them.

Comment: It seems the OP really wants to catch the exception when he has a bad URL.  The real solution is to combine techniques to prevent a bad URL from getting passed to Mechanize in the first place.  A combination of this technique along with 'scrubbing' the backslashes with something like `decoded_url = URI.unescape(url).gsub('\\','/')` should be employed.