# Rails URI::regexp match with no scheme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri, regexp-replace

I need to validate URL with URI::regexp but some URLs have no scheme.

I tried using,

```
URI::regexp(["http", "http]) 
URI::regexp(%w(http https tel)
```

but they cannot validate empty scheme such as "www.google.com" "google.com".

How can I include/validate such URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Try `URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.regexp[:ABS_URI]` from the [source](https://apidock.com/ruby/URI/regexp/class) itself. It also fails in specific conditions as mentioned in "[How to check if a URL is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805761/check-if-url-is-valid-ruby/4395267#4395267)", but if you are ok with it, it's good to go:

```
def valid?(url)
  !!(url =~ URI::ABS_URI || url =~ URI::REL_URI)
end
```

Comment: This is a valid url here: valid?('foo')

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = %w|www.google.com
         www.http.com
         http://google.com
         https://google.com|.map do |e|
  e.gsub(/\A(?!http)/, "http://")
end
#⇒ [
#   [0] "http://www.google.com",
#   [1] "http://www.http.com",
#   [2] "http://google.com",
#   [3] "https://google.com"
# ]
_.map { |e| URI::regexp(%w|http https|) =~ e }
#⇒ [0, 0, 0, 0]
```